# View docx, PPTX, XLSX files before uploading to server in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just need to preview a doc file before uploading, is it possible?
I am getting base64 of uploading file (which can be pdf, png, and jpg) and can view it in the iframe happily. But in case of base64 of Doc, Docx, PPTX, and XLSX  I am unable to show in the iframe.

```
<input type="file" #file placeholder="Choose file" (change)="uploadFile(file)" >
<iframe [src]="Base64File"></iframe>

uploadFile(file) {
 let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(data.files[0]); 
    reader.onload = (_event) => { 
  this.Base64File= this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(reader.result);
}
```

I have also used ngx-doc-viewer, and the issue with it is that it does not accept base64 to view a file, it works with path only, and during uploading, I can't get file path from the local hard drive and in case if I get, angular will not allow me to use that path.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score -2):

I also had this issue, iframe tag is used for viewing html document and i solved by adding ng-doc-viewer, a npm package this will download your file and then you can view it use (npm i ngx-doc-viewer) to install the package

import the NgxDocViewerModule in root module and use the following code

<ngx-doc-viewer [url]="baseimg" viewer="url" style="width:80vh;height:80vh;">

Also refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-doc-viewer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31858277)

Comment: But if i am not wrong isn't above package only show document from the path and not from base64 data??
How do you did it share the code if you done it using base64